# Allternate to get contens by hitting a url?

Tags: java, php, dwr

when i hit url i get:

//#DWR-REPLY
if (window.dwr) dwr.engine._remoteHandleBatchException({ name:'org.directwebremoting.extend.ServerException', message:'The specified call count is not a number: null' });
else if (window.parent.dwr) window.parent.dwr.engine._remoteHandleBatchException({ name:'org.directwebremoting.extend.ServerException', message:'The specified call count is not a number: null' });

Comment: $var = file_get_contents('http://www.shopcj.com/dwr/call/plaincall/DispDwrController.selectItemPagedList.dwr');

Comment: $var gets the above content //#DWR-REPLY....

Comment: Please don't hit nor kick the URLs! I protest any form of physical violence against the innocent URLs.

Comment: @user3869786: Fine. And what do you expected to get ? I think you won't get any valueable answer, if you not ask more detailed and specific.